# How to disable button until condition satisfy in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```js
   isMobile(e) {
      let char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode); // Get the character
      if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(char)) return true;
      // Match with regex
      else e.preventDefault(); // If not match, don't add to input text
      
    },
```

```js
export default {
  name: "HelloWworld",

  data: function () {
    return {
      mobdis: false,
      mobile: "",
      maxmobile: 10,
    };
  },

  validations: {
    computed: {
      isDisabled: function () {
        return !this.mobdis;
      },
    },
  },
```

```html
<input
  class="input-section label-set"
  style="padding-left: 75px"
  type="text"
  id="mobdis"
  v-model="mobdis"
  v-model.trim="$v.mobile.$model"
  :class="{ 'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.mobile) }"
  placeholder="Enter registerd mobile number"
  :maxlength="maxmobile"
  v-on:keypress="isMobile($event)"
/>
<div v-if="!$v.mobile.minLength" class="invalid-feedback">
  Kindly check phone
  {{ $v.mobile.$params.maxLength.min }} number.
</div>
  
<button
  class="sendotp-button"
  :disabled="isDisabled"
  v-on:click="isHidden = true"
>
  SEND
</button>
```

How to set Maxlength condition for button in Vuejs?

Disabling of button is working fine, but maxlength condition is not satisfying, Even if i try to enter 1 digit, button is enabling..

Added the regex code also.

Comment: what does your `isMobile` function/method do?

Comment: It checks for the regex value.

Comment: Where in isMobile, i have given condition like, to accept only 0-9 digits

Answer (score 0):

try validating the `mobdis` with js

something like this:

```
export default {
  name: "HelloWworld",

  data: function () {
    return {
      mobdis: false,
      mobile: "",
      maxmobile: 10,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    isMobile(event) {
      /* other codes */
      this.$nextTick(function () {
        if (event.value.length > 9) {
          // check if this field (number) has value lenght 10
          this.mobdis = true;
        } else {
          this.mobdis = false;
        }
      });
      /* other codes */
    },
  },

  /* validations: {
    computed: {
      isDisabled: function () {
        return !this.mobdis;
      },
    },
  }, */
};
```

Comment: Tried this, But condition is not working.

Comment: Any other way of doing it in vue part??

Comment: what shows if you `console.log('this.mobdis')`?

Comment: this.mobdis. It's not displaying any value. I think it's because we are not passing any value to mobdis, So mobdis we are passing as ID, and utilizing in the function.

Comment: I have edited the answer please have a look

Comment: Tried but  it  doesn't work. May be because of pure JavaScript code, So anything can be done Vuejs?